# showing equality holds $(1+x/n)^n\geq (1+x/10)^{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show that $(1+x/n)^n\geq (1+x/10)^{10}$? (for $n\geq 10$)

I see that if I consider $n\to\infty$, the LHS approaches $e^x$, but that's all I could really see.

Please assume that $x\in[0,\infty)$

Comment: It's not true. Take $n=11$ and $x=-11$.

Comment: Oh, actually, my domain for $x$ is $[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Since the two expressions are equal at $n=10$, it is sufficient to
show that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial n}(1+x/n)^{n}\geq0 \text{ for } n\geq1 \text{ and } x\geq 0.$$

You can check that this is equivalent to showing $$\log((n+x)/n)\geq x/(n+x)\text{ for } n\geq1 \text{ and } x\geq 0.$$

Moreover, this inequality follows immediately from [a well-known lower bound on the natural logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm).

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1 \times (1-\frac1n) ... (1-\frac{k-1}{n})}{k!} x^k \geq \sum_{k=0}^{10} \frac{1 \times (1-\frac{1}{10}) ... (1-\frac{k-1}{10})}{k!} x^k = (1+ \frac{x}{10})^{10}$$

In fact, same proof shows that $(1+x/n)^n$ is increasing in $n$ (fixed $x>0$).